# How to generate dynamic "Reply-To:" based on "Message-ID:"? [+detail]

Tags: email, emacs, elisp, emacs24, gnus

How can you generate a dynamic "Reply-To:"  (and "From:") header in emacs/gnus based on Message-ID **of the created message**?  I would like to use external (perl) script to generate a dynamic `+detail` part based on the "Messaged-ID:" header.

```
user+detail@example.net
```

I have managed to create a header with content generated by my external script. The script gets usenet group name as command line parameter. I would like to pass it the message-id value too.

**My current code**
~/.emacs :

```
'(gnus-posting-styles ("^pl\\.test$" ("Reply-To" message-make-reply-to)))
```

~/.gnus

```
(defun message-make-reply-to()
  (my-script ".../reply-to.pl" (message-fetch-field "Message-Id")))

(defun my-script(path &optional param) ....
```

The problem: the script does not receive message-id as its parameter (my-script gets correctly explicitly set parameter)

Comment: Why don't you handle the task entirely from within Emacs/Gnus? And which message-id are you talking about, the one from the new reply or the one from the message being replied to?

Comment: @schaueho 1) If you tell how to handle it in Emacs/Gnus then I should be able to add perl part 2) I want new new message-id (it is generated by my Emacs/Gnus customizations)

Comment: The process you have in mind is still too unclear to me to give a complete answer but I believe you cannot get away without coding a small routine in Emacs Lisp. Hence some pointers: Fetching the message id from the new reply would be possible with `(message-fetch-field "Message-Id")`, generating the Reply-To field could be done by using `message-goto-reply-to` and then messing around with the line content or by `(message-replace-header "Reply-To" "my value")`.

Comment: It does not seem to work. I use the following to execute scripts: `defun my-script(path &optional param) ...`. The dollowing in lisp function used to generated X-Reply-To have not passed Message-Id: to the script (my-script ".../script"  (message-fetch-field "Message-Id"))

Comment: If you add some code to your question, it would be easier to give help.

Comment: You might need to set `message-generate-headers-first`, cg. [the relevant message documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/message/Message-Headers.html)

Comment: `'(message-generate-headers-first t)` have not fixed "unset script param" problem. Message-Id is on both message-required-news-headers and message-required-mail-headers. P.S. I use custom lisp function to generate Message-Id.

Comment: You probably need to ensure that the Message-ID is generated first, this might not be the case depending on various variables. I also don't know when your custom lisp function kicks in.

Comment: @schaueho  I have defined `message-make-message-id` lisp function to generate message-id

Comment: I deleted my old answer (sorry for the misunderstanding) and added a new one.  All the credit should really go to @schaueho, whose comments greatly helped to put together this answer.  Please let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;; Make sure the Message-ID header is present in newly created messages
(setq message-generate-headers-first '(Message-ID))

;; Prevent emacs from resetting the Message-ID before the message is sent.
(setq message-deletable-headers
      (remove 'Message-ID message-deletable-headers))

(setq gnus-posting-styles
      '(("^pl\\.test$"
         ("Reply-To" '(message-make-reply-to)))))
```

Note the additional quote and parentheses around `message-make-reply-to`.  The explanation for this is that the function is run at different times, depending on whether it's given as a symbol or as a quoted s-expression.

- If given as symbol, it is run when a lambda function is added to `message-setup-hook`.  That happens in a `message-mode-hook`, i.e. right after the new buffer is created and switched into `message-mode`.  The cause for this is some wild quoting/unquoting of values during creation of the lambda function.
- If given as a quoted sexpr, evaluation is delayed until after the buffer is filled with initial values.  It is close to the last code which is run on message setup.

#### Alternative Solution (without `gnus-posting-styles`)

In cases where the new header should be added to every new message, the `Reply-To` header can also be set using the `message-header-setup-hook`.  A custom hook needs to be defined to add the header for each new message.

```
(defun reply-to-message-header-setup-hook ()
  (let* ((msg-id (message-fetch-field "Message-ID"))
         (reply-to (my-script ".../reply-to-pl" msg-id)))
    (message-add-header (concat "Reply-To: " reply-to))))

;; Call the hook every time a new message is created
(add-hook 'message-header-setup-hook 'reply-to-message-header-setup-hook)

;; Make sure the Message-ID header is present in newly created messages
(setq message-generate-headers-first '(Message-ID))
```

Comment: It works after some modifications: `(defun reply-to-message-header-setup-hook ()
    (message-add-header (concat "Reply-To: " (my-script ".../reply-to-pl" (list (message-fetch-field "Message-ID"))))))`. I wanted it to be selected only for some posts/messages by gnus-posting-styles but I accept the answer as the best offered.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip After re-reading the respective gnus code, I found the answer to be much much simpler than what I was proposing: `(setq gnus-posting-styles ("^pl\\.test$" (Reply-To '(message-make-reply-to))))` (note the extra quote/parens) should work as long as the `message-generate-headers-first` value is set as above.  I'll edit the answer to include this.

Comment: **There is a problem**: The script gets Message-Id as presented in message compose buffer **BUT** the message is send with another Message-Id.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip We have to remove Message-ID from message-deletable-headers to prevent it being reset when the message is sent: `(setq message-deletable-headers (remove 'Message-ID message-deletable-headers))`

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Great! Thanks for being patient, debugging this with you was fun.