# rewrite outgoing messages/posts by external program/filter

Tags: email, emacs, elisp, emacs24, gnus

I would like to rewrite fully composed emacs-gnus messages/posts (**headers and body**) by external filter 
(external program/script, STDIN to STDOUT).
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your function to [`message-send-hook`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mail-Sending.html):

```
(add-hook 'message-send-hook 'my-message-rewrite)
(defun my-message-rewrite ()
  "Pipe the current message buffer through the command and replace it with the output."
  (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max)
                           "my command line with args"
                           t t))
```

Obviously you do not have to resort to a shell command, your lisp function can do much more.

Notes:

1. This hook is run "quite early"; you might want to use `message-send-mail-hook` instead - it is run "very late".
2. Let me reiterate: you are swimming against the stream here. You do *not* want to do this. Please ask a separate question on emacs.SE describing what your perl script does and you will see how much easier it is to accomplish with Lisp.

Comment: My perl skills are much better than my (e)lisp skills :-)

Comment: Once upon a time I said something like that too. I learned better since then. Lisp is so much more powerful, easier to use, to debug, to develop, to learn!

Comment: It seems that the script receives onlt message body.  I wanted to rewrite full message (headers & body) - sorry for lack of precision.

Comment: Sorry, I expected classic "empty line" as header/body separator. Emacs-gnus uses something different :-)

Comment: indeed, and this is yet another reason not to do what you are doing.

Comment: 1) `message-send-news-hook` fails with utf8 chars in message body 2) I wanted 2A) per newsgroup time zone in Date: header (e.g. different TZ for pl.* and uk.* posts ) 2B) Reply-To: header with +detail based based on Message-Id:

Comment: I am not sure I quite understand your last comment - could you ask a separate question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271533/per-newsgroup-timezone-in-date-header https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310574/how-to-generate-dynamic-reply-to-based-on-message-id-detail